# ValueError at /createPost Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser

Tags: python, html, django

Hello Guys I'm trying to post an image file using Django. I don't know what is happening and I got another error while trying to fix one so please see the code and I got **ValueError at /createPost
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000020C1B569F40>>": "Post.author" must be a "User" instance** this error I don't know what's going on, Im beginner so.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    post = Post.objects.order_by("-pub_date")
    context = {
    "posts": post
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", context)


def post_create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST,request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
        content = form.cleaned_data["content"]
        img = form.cleaned_data["img"]
        username = request.user
        post = Post.objects.create(title = title, content = content, img = img, author = username)
        post.save
        return redirect("posts:home")
    else:
        form = PostForm()

    context = {
    "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "postcreate.html", context)
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    content = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = "static/my_post_pic", null = True, blank = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} // {self.author}"
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', "content", "img")
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

app_name = "posts"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name = "home"),
    path("createPost", views.post_create, name = "createPost")
]
```

postCreate.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}



{% block content %}
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name = "title" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Title">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Content</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name = "content" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Content">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name = "img" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user did not log in, hence the error. You can work with the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) to redirect to the login page in such case:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def post_create(request):
    # …
```